# DNSMASQ serve different dns results to different subnets

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

In my network infrastructure I have multiple subnets intended to segregate different types of devices. I would like the ability to serve different DNS responses from different DNS servers based on the requesting subnet. For example I'd like to use Google's DNS for one subnet but say CloudFlare's anti-malware DNS for another. I would also like the ability to then further lock down by using different "address" declarations on the different subnets.

One way that some people accomplish the first part is to use the "dhcp-option" declaration to serve different server addresses to the different subnets but this kind of defeats the purpose of DNSMASQ and turns it basically into just a DHCP server and also defeats using a firewall to restrict access to port 53 to control any hard-coded dns servers.

The other option I've seen is to run 2 instances of DNSMASQ however this creates a highly customized setup which doesn't allow any of the system level configuration files or run scripts which I'd like to avoid.

So I'm hoping someone can offer a solution for this.